# Wicket - AjaxEventBehavior not rendered properly

Tags: java, wicket

Look at the following snippet.

```
   add(new AjaxEventBehavior("onclick") {

        private boolean toggle = false;

        @Override
        protected void onEvent(AjaxRequestTarget target)
        {
            log.debug("onEvent: " + toggle);
            if (toggle)
            {
                toggle = false;
                target.prependJavaScript("toogle(true)");
            } 
            else
            {
                toggle = true;
                target.prependJavaScript("toogle(false)");
            }
         }        
     });
```

But after the page rendering [no errors, warnings], I could see no event associated to the DOM [verified by means of firebug]. Even the debug log was never printed.

Is there any option in wicket to verify the behavior is added or not?

Comment: Wicket uses event registration, so you won't find 'onclick'-attributes in the html. Check the markup-tag of the component, is it a <wicket:container>?

Comment: nope. it's just appended under <div wicket:id="image" class="image"/>

Comment: Removing the attribute "id" from matching html markup element resolved the issue, now I could see the behaviours are properly attached. Anyone, any idea what's happening to the core?

Comment: You should never have HTML ids in your markup: for Wicket these take precedence over a generated markup id.

Answer (score 0):

You should iterate trougth Behaviors added to this component to verify your one is added:

```
for (Behavior behavior : component.getBehaviors()) {
    if(AjaxEventBehavior.class.equals(behavior.getClass())) {
        // it works    
    }
}
```

Comment: There is a shortcut: `component.getBehaviors(AjaxEventBehavior.class)`

Answer (score 0):

The behavior won't contribute its JavaScript if the component it is attached on is either invisible or disabled.

BTW both of your `prependJavaScript()` calls use the same content `toggle(true)`.

Comment: I've edited the js now, and actually the component is attached and visible. Only in some cases I can't find the behavior is attached, this should be due to some overlapping of codes I guess.

Answer (score 0):

You should (almost) never have HTML ids in your markup:

For Wicket these ids take precedence over generated unique markup ids. If the id is present multiple times on the page (e.g. if you use a component multiple times), all Ajax handlers will attach to the first markup tag with that id.